# Show years on combo

Tags: c#, windows, combobox

work on **C# window vs2008**.I have a **combo** ,need to **fill** this combo by the current year ,previous and next ten years,

Suppose: `current year=DateTime.Now.Year`,i need add next and previous 10 years with the current year,then need to show in combo.**How to show that in combo**.plz send  syntax.

Have some query plz ask.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            for (int i = year - 10; i <= year + 10; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use in loop:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(x).Year
```

where x = {-10;10}

Comment: i think shamim also wants code to add values on combobox.thats why he highlighted "How to show that in combo"

Answer (score 0):

**i use devex combo control**

```
  List<int> data = new List<int>();
                int nCurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 10;
                foreach (int yearCount in Enumerable.Range(1, 20))
                {
                    data.Add(nCurrentYear + yearCount);
                }
                Combo.Properties.DataSource = data;
                Combo.EditValue = DateTime.Now.Year;
```